# What is a better way to return array?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a cascade of functions which return arrays. What is a better practice for returning? Should I clone every array in functions or clone it in main function or I shouldn't clone it at all?

1)

```
static double[] a() {
   double[] res = new double[3];
   ...
   return res;
}

static double[] b() {
   double[] res = a();
   ...
   return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   double[] arr = b().clone;
}
```

2)

```
static double[] a() {
   double[] res = new double[3];
   ...
   return res;
}

static double[] b() {
   double[] res = a();
   ...
   return res.clone;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   double[] arr = b();
}
```

3) ...

I need a piece of advice for good practice in such cases.

Comment: define *better*

Comment: Why do you think you should clone in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning Arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869741/returning-arrays-in-java)

Comment: @Blake Not remotely a duplicate of that.

Comment: better means maybe there is a pattern for this case which says that I should avoid returning not cloned array from function otherwise it'll be anti-pattern

Comment: @Blake - I can't see anything in common with my question except words "array" and "function"

Comment: Why do you even think option 2 would be a good idea? You are unnecessarily creating an array and immediately throwing it away by assigning something else. You may want to study the basics of Java some more before asking questions.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - ok, I think I just oversimplified my code so much that now it looks too silly. Also I missed some key features. Anyway, thank all of you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that you should almost never return an array. You have to make Sophie's choice between losing control of mutation and making potentially expensive allocations.

Instead:

- If the caller really wants an array for specific performance reasons (which is rare), have them pass in their own array instance and `arrayCopy` the relevant data to it. Return the length. This is how e.g. `InputStream.read` works.
- If the caller wants to examine the data and doesn't care if it changes later, use an `ArrayList` or similar internally, and then return a `Collections.unmodifiableList` view of it.
- If the returned values can't change and writes are more common that reads, return a copy and make sure it's unmodifiable. This is API compatible with the next point if you change your mind.
- If the returned values can't change and reads are more common than writes, use an immutable data structure internally and simply return a reference. This is API compatible with the previous point.

Comment: Thank you, you understood my question more precisely than others

Answer (score 1):

The first way you have seems fine, but the clone() is likely unnecessary.

In main you could just directly set arr to b(), every time you call b() it will be making a new array as a() is already making a new array

so it would look like...

```
static double[] a() {
   double[] res = new double[3];
   ...
   return res;
}

static double[] b() {
   double[] res = a();
   ...
   return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   double[] arr = b();
}
```