# how to make an array function return a value

Tags: java, arrays, function, arraylist

So to summarize my problem, I want the function int[] get_marks() to be able to return the array, but I don't know how to get my ArrayList marks to convert into an array which I can use the return thing for. I need the arraylist to be converted because I need to be able to find the frequency and mode of the array (parts of the code I have not started because I can't figure out how to convert the arraylist).

Below is my comment less code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {

  public static int[] get_marks(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<>();
    final int FLAG = -1;
    int entries = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter your marks. Type -1 when done.");

    while (entries != FLAG){
    entries = input.nextInt();
    
    if (entries >=0 && entries <= 100){
      marks.add(entries);
    } else if (entries == FLAG) {
      break;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid entry. Marks must be between 0-100.");
      }
    }
    input.close();

    System.out.println("Your Marks are: " + marks);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    get_marks();
    
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can convert the arrayList into an array and return that. Your question is not very clear to me. You said you want to return a function ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning Arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869741/returning-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Create an int[] the length of the ArrayList then put each element of the ArrayList into the new array. Then return the array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return the ArrayList marks?

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> get_marks(){return marks}
```

Also, you could make the method return void. Is there any reason you need it to return a value in main?

To elaborate, if you make it `void`, it will just do all the calculations and culminate in `System.out.println("Your Marks are: " + marks);`. Given your code, is that not what you want? If so, make `get_marks()` return void:

```
public static void get_marks() {//run the code, print the marks, etc.}
```

Why do you need the `get_marks()` method? You may not have posted all your code, but if this is all your code, just get rid of `get_marks()` and put it all in `main()`. If all `main()` does is call `get_marks()`, consolidate the methods.

Comment: thats just one part of the code. theres more parts where i need to find frequency and mode of the array which is why I can't have it as a void function

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to simply return an `ArrayList<Integer>` or even better a `List<Integer>`. If you insist on returning an `int[]`, your question is a [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array).

Comment: that doesn't work for me